# How to find the Big O of this recurrence relation?

Tags: big-o, recurrence

Can you provide a step to step solution to solve this.

Find that `T(n)` is `Big O(?)`:

> T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + 4n

I have searched for solutions but the most i find are of this type:

> T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

Which i solve with the master theorem but i have a problem applying what i know to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The Master Theorem applies to recurrences of the form: T(n) = aT(<sup>n</sup>/<sub>b</sub>) + f(n).

You want to find the values of `a`, `b`, and `f(n)`.

In this case you have multiple `aT(n/b)` terms so we can use both to find the more *dominant* term.

T(n) = T(<sup>n</sup>/<sub>2</sub>) + 4n, (`a = 1`, `b = 2`, `f(n) = 4n`), Master Theorem shows that `T(n) = Θ(n)`

T(n) = T(<sup>n</sup>/<sub>3</sub>) + 4n, (`a = 1`, `b = 3`, `f(n) = 4n`), Master Theorem hows that `T(n) = Θ(n)`

Since they are both `Θ(n)`, the complexity is `Θ(n)`